# coord_cartesian Not Working with Stacked Bar Chart and Date Objects in R in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a straightforward stacked bar chart generated using ggplot2 in Shiny where I'm using date objects:

Data:

```
reg_year <- as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01"))

conv_year <- as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01"))

df <- data.frame(conv_year, reg_year)
```

In Shiny I am trying to render a stacked bar chart and use `coord_cartesian` to 'zoom in'

```
ui: 

outputPlot("myplot")

server: 

output$myplot <- renderPlot ({

ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=df, aes(x= conv_year, fill = reg_year)) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2021-01-01")))

})
```

The stacked bar plot renders properly ***without*** `coord_cartesian`.   However, when I add the line for `coord_cartesian` I get an empty figure.

Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In `output$myplot < renderPlot` you're missing the second half of the assignment arrow. Otherwise it works fine for me.

Comment: Very strange.  the second half of the assignment arrow is not the issue (typo in question).  Not rendering properly for me.   You comment suggests it may be something in my environment.

Comment: Does it render properly in a normal R environment? Meaning outside of shiny?

Comment: No it isn't.  I get background, Y axis, x axis label, and legend but no bars

Comment: I got it to render locally.  Not in Shiny

Comment: How about a minimal app with only this plot? Try to isolate the problem

Comment: So here is a partial fix - apparently in Shiny when rendering the plot using ggplot I need to re-define conv_year and reg_year where used as dates using `as.Date`.  Like this `geom_bar(data=df, aes(x= as.Date(conv_year), fill = as.Date(reg_year))`  .  This is strange because these columns are already date objects.    Still I not get a plot but not  stacked plot - so something appears to be off with 'fill'.

Comment: It works correctly if I don't define reg_year as a date.   VERY weird.   posting my solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact cause of this but apparently in Shiny there are slightly different syntax requirements.   `conv_year` and `reg_year` are defined as dates in my dataframe in Shiny (not shown here).  Apparently, Shiny somehow 'forgets' they are dates when trying to render in ggplot in Shiny.   The following renders properly:

```
server: 

output$myplot <- renderPlot ({

ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=df, aes(x= as.Date(conv_year), fill = reg_year)) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2021-01-01")))

})
```

`conv_year` needs to be explicitly stated as a date for `x` in aes but fill must ***not*** be a date.

I don't know why these differences occur but they do.